# Connecting to MySQL with SSL server certificate only

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I have to connect to MySQL 8 from an old PHP 5.3.3 application. I have no permission to upgrade PHP version.

The requirement is that the connection must be through SSL but not using SSL authentication. MySQL server is configured to use a cipher for connection but does not require the client to provide any SSL authentication certificates at all.

I used console commands to verify that SSL connection works from my machine to the server:

```
mysql -u username -p -h domain.com --ssl-mode=REQUIRED

mysql> \s
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256

mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
+---------------+---------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                     |
+---------------+---------------------------+
| Ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 |
+---------------+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

So, the current connection is encrypted using the server certificate and accepting it silently without any CA validation.

Then I tried to reproduce that in PHP using mysqli:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();

// I've no idea how to tell PHP to ignore all certificates but still use SSL as provided by the server;
// even passing random crap to ssl_set() doesn't change anything at all - not even failed connection
$mysqli->ssl_set(null, null, null, null, null);

$mysqli->real_connect($mysqliDomain, "username", "pass", "db", "3306", null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
// Not sure about MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL - PHP doc says it shouldn't be used from application side; but it doesn't work anyway, no matter if I use it or not.
// In addtion, disabling server cert verification MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT
// is not supported in PHP 5.3.3

$res = $mysqli->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';");
while ( $row = $res->fetch_array() ) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

No matter what I try, the result is empty cipher value, which means the connection is not encrypted:

```
Array ( [0] => Ssl_cipher [Variable_name] => Ssl_cipher [1] => [Value] => )
```

How to solve this?

Comment: _“I have no permission to upgrade PHP [5.3.3.] version.”_ - that is not a stance anyone even ever so remotely interested in the security of their web apps should take …

Comment: value vs. Value?

Comment: @ChrisWhite  Nice catch. Still didn't change the outcome - the resulting Ssl_cipher value is always empty.

Comment: @04FS  "The customer is always right". Unless I prove that the problem could be solved in higher PHP versions, but I'm not sure about that because almost all examples on the internet show using `ssl_set` with client certificates which I don't need.

Comment: "Note that MySQL Native Driver does not support SSL before PHP 5.3.3, so calling this function when using MySQL Native Driver will result in an error. MySQL Native Driver is enabled by default on Microsoft Windows from PHP version 5.3 onwards." -https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php

This error could be silent and downgrade the connection. Did you check which driver your php version is using?

Comment: Looking at https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0 there were multiple bugs involved when dealing with ssl_set. Make sure you are using at least 5.3.3 and also consider trying PDO instead of mysqli (just to see if it works)

Comment: phpinfo reports `mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $` , so it's native driver indeed. But it silently falls back to non-encrypted connection without any error messages.

Comment: @JustAMartin *"The customer is always right"*  And [you're not doing your job](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/version_id-97802/PHP-PHP-5.3.3.html).  There are three 10.0 worst-possible-severity remote exploit vulnerabilities **that have been public for 7-8 years** in PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  - the customer doesn't care much (because hasn't yet been bitten by any of those security issues), and also it's an intranet-only web application. And it's often about money - not wanting to pay someone to upgrade their servers and then deal with consequences (e.g. unexpected PHP warning messages breaking layouts of their neat internal websites etc. etc.)